# Parameters in "cells"-method

Tags: vb.net, export-to-excel, epplus

I'm new in VB.NET. I want to export Excel from VB.NET, and I'm using EPPlus for my project.

What are the four parameters of `ws.cells()` in this code?

Code:

```
 Imports OfficeOpenXml
 Imports OfficeOpenXml.Style
 Imports System.IO
 Public Class excelExport
 Private Access As New DBControl
 Public Sub myReport()
    Dim saveDialog As New SaveFileDialog
    saveDialog.Filter = "Excel File (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
    saveDialog.FilterIndex = 1

    If saveDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Try

            Dim file As FileInfo = New FileInfo(saveDialog.FileName)

            ' Ensures we create a new workbook
            If (file.Exists) Then
                file.Delete()
            End If

            Dim pck As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage(file)

            ' Add a new worksheet to the empty workbook
            Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1")
            '  Load data from DataTable to the worksheet
            ws.Cells("A1").Value = "new"
            ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns()

            '  Add some styling
            Dim rng As ExcelRange = ws.Cells(1, 1, 1, 10) '<----------  This code

            rng.Style.Font.Bold = True
            rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(79, 129, 189))
            rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White)

            ' Save the new workbook
            pck.Save()


            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Excel file {0} generated successfully.", file.Name))

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show("Failed to export to Excel. Original error: " + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question is mainly asking for an opinion, which is not what this site is for. For what it is worth, I have found EPPlus useful for creating Excel files.

The answer to your second question is that the four arguments in the `Cells` method are:

1. The number of the first row to be included in the Range.
2. The number of the first column to be included in the Range.
3. The number of the last row to be included in the Range.
4. The number of the last column to be included in the Range.